# Change password form when using password_hash

Tags: php

So I use password_hash in my users registration. So now I want to make that the user can change their password when they want to.

After countless videos on youtube I went ahead and wrote up this.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    include("checklogin.php");
    check_login();
    include("dbconnection.php");
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['Change']))
    {
    $ret=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['login']."'");
    
    $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($ret);
    
    function console_log( $ret ){
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $ret ) .')';
        echo '</script>';
      }
    
    $num=mysqli_fetch_array($ret);
    if($numrow>0)
    {
      // CHECK FOR PASSWORD MATCH
      if(password_verify($_POST['oldpass'], $num['password']))
        {
            $hashed = password_hash($_POST[('newpass')], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $con = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE user SET password ='".$hashed."' where email='".$_SESSION['login']."'");
            $_SESSION['msg1']="Password Has Been Changed!";
        }
       else
        {
            $_SESSION['msg1']="Error, the Old Password doesn't match!";
        }
    }
    }

?>
```

But when I click on the submit, nothing happens and it doesn't seem to be updating. I'm not sure where I've done wrong and I'm quite new using php so I don't know how to setup debugging with Visual Studio Code.

```
function check_login()
{
if(strlen($_SESSION['login'])==0)
    {   
        $host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uri  = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        $extra="index.php";     
        $_SESSION["login"]="";
        header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
    }
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: can you add the `check_login` function unless you know categorically that is OK. Also - why turn OFF error reporting whilst trying to develop this?

Comment: Yes this is the check_login function, wait sorry I'll add it to the main post.

Comment: there are no functions here ( other than `console_log` ).. add the real code otherwise you are hindering those that might help

Comment: Ah, about the error-reporting, I'm not sure whether it's on or off. How does one check for that?

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` is OFF, try `error_reporting(E_ALL);` for development - [more info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: You should also adopt the practise of using [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as a matter of course when performing queries that use variables for input

Comment: `$_POST[('newpass')]` ~ remove the `()` - ie :`$_POST['newpass']`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll learn more on using prepared statements and just changed the newpass stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment - you should use `prepared statements` rather than embedding variables directly in the SQL. Apart from mitigating SQL injection attacks it also helps when `strings` might have strange characters that can sometimes break conventional quotes - and a password might well have `special characters`

I hope the following might help a little with the prepared statement side of things.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    include 'checklogin.php';
    include 'dbconnection.php';
    
    # default values
    $hash=false;
    $message='Error, the Old Password does not match!';

    

    # ensure the user knows the current password before changing
    $sql='select `password` from `user` where `email`=? limit 1';
    $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['login'] );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result( $hash );
    $stmt->fetch();
    
    
    
    if( $hash && password_verify( $_POST['oldpass'], $hash ) ){
        # close old statement
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
        
        
        

        # generate new hash
        $hash=password_hash( $_POST['newpass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
        
        
        

        # the user has verified the old password, a new hash 
        # has been generated so allow them to change it.
        $sql='update `user` set `password`=? where `email`=?';
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $hash, $_SESSION['login'] );
        $status=$stmt->execute();
        
        
        
        if( $status && $stmt->affected_rows > 0 ) {
            $message='Password has been changed!';
        }
    }
    
    # set the session variable
    $_SESSION['msg1']=$message;
?>
```

The `check_login` function could likely be simplified:

```
<?php
    # checklogin.php
    
    function check_login(){
        if( !isset( $_SESSION ) or empty( $_SESSION['login'] ) ) exit( header('Location: /index.php'));
        return true;
    }

    check_login();
?>
```